# HTML \ CSS \ style: hiding an HTML container and its HTML child controls

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML template rendering problem: on an HTML page, i have 2 parent root containers (<div>, <p>... Whatever) that have sub-containers and HTML controls laid out on them.

I would like that, when the 1st HTML container is hidden with all its children, then the 2nd one is visible. And vice versa. I wanted to do this, by injecting the word "hidden" in one of my 2 parent root containers, and "" in the other. My problem is that injecting "hidden" into a <p> tag doesn't hide its child containers and controls.

Afterwards, i've looked at the side of an injection of a style that could be named ".hideMeWithMyChildren". I saw, too, that there were selectors of style ("<" i.e. "MeAndMyParent", or ">" i.e. "MeAndMyChildren").

Now, my question is: how can i write a named style (for example ".hideMeWithMyChildren") that uses this selector too, in order to hide recursively a HTLM container and its children?

Regards.

Comment: Plz share a piece of your HTML code with the elements you want to hide

Answer (score 0):

Okay: here is a shared example of code, below.
{+HIDDEN_IF_USER_DOES_NOT_TALK_IN_ENGLISH+} is a transparent tag like "Twig" that i want to dynamically replace (with the fpWeb's template engine) by 'hidden' or '' i.e. nothing:

```
<div {+HIDDEN_IF_USER_DOES_NOT_TALK_IN_ENGLISH+}>
    Hello, from the root-parent DIV element
    <p>
        Hello, from its child sub-paragraph
    </p>
</div>
```

➔ In fact, i've found: if i inject 'style="display: none;"' instead of a simple 'hidden', then both the parent <div> and its child sub-paragraph <p> are now hidden.
It's solved, for me.